# What does throws statement mean in java?

Tags: java

Also, what does `throws NumberFormatException, IOException` mean? I keep trying to use `BufferedReader` by saying

```
BufferedReader nerd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
```

but `BufferedReader` won't work unless `throws NumberFormatException, IOException` is put in.

Comment: Did you check the documentation?

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/throwing.html

Comment: ever thought of puuting the code in try catch and there catching these exceptions one by one [ if jdk <=1.6] , or at the same time [ if jdk =1.7]

Comment: Did you consider reading the manual first?? Here you go : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/TOC.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the purpose of the 'throws' statement in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6553940/whats-the-purpose-of-the-throws-statement-in-java)

Comment: Related question with useful answers: [Why is “throws Exception” necessary when calling a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11589302/86967)

Answer (score 5):

The `throws` keyword indicates that a certain method can potentially "throw" a certain exception. You need to handle a possible `IOException` (and possibly other exceptions) either with a `try-catch` block or by adding `throws IOException, (...)` to your method declaration. Something like this:

```
public void foo() throws IOException /* , AnotherException, ... */ {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    in.readLine();
    // etc.
    in.close();
}


public void foo() {
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    try {
        in.readLine();
        // etc.
        in.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle the exception 
    } /* catch (AnotherException e1) {...} ... */
}
```

Comment: Does `IOException` need to be defined anywhere? If it's an Object, it has to have a `class` declaration right?

Answer (score 4):

Throws clause is used to declare the exceptions that are not handled by a particular method and is an instruction to the callers to either handle these explicitly or rethrow them up in the call hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

The throws statement means that the function, may 'throw' an error. Ie spit out an error that will end the current method, and make the next 'try catch' block on the stack handle it.

In this case you can either add 'throws....' to the method declaration or you can do:

```
try {
    // code here
} catch (Exception ex) {
    // what to do on error here
}
```

Read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/ for more info.